# Prevent child class methods from firing?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I am sure this question has been asked before, but I searched and couldn't find it so I apologize in advance for duplicating content here on SO.

That being said: In Objective-C, in an overridden method you can call the parent class method using something like `[super methodName]`
but how do prevent the rest of the code from executing in the child class from the parent? It could because it's Friday, but I stared at my monitor for a few minutes and couldn't get past it in my head.

Example (in child class):

```
- (void)methodName
{
    [super methodName];

    //Everything below this line shouldn't execute if tell it not to from the parent
    NSString *aString = @"This should never be called.";
}
```

Help me out! I know there's a simple solution, but my brain just isn't picking it up today...

Comment: This is a code smell to me. As soon as you need to start doing things like this in your code, you need to take a step back and ask yourself why you need to be doing this, and then re-architect your code so you don't have to.

Comment: @Jasarien I agree. I'm maintaining some poorly designed code. This isn't something I'm used to doing in my code hence why I was unfamiliar. This was a end-of-day Friday patch. A re-architecture is currently underway. Thanks for the advice though!

Comment: I could easily see how you could want to do something like this if you were checking for an internet connection. You want to check for an internet connection in the parent class. You don't want to repeat code and do it in every single child class. So let say child class calls super, and in super you detect no internet connection, so now you want to prevent all the child classes from continuing on. What do you do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could test the object type and determine if you do or don't want to run additional code for example:

```
if (![myObject isKindOfClass:[MyChildObject class]]
{
    //run only superclass code
}
```

As I write this, I can't help but wonder if you don't have some issue with how you setup your classes though.  If your design is spot on, you shouldn't have to go through these kinds of contortions.

Answer (score 1):

You could maybe have another function returning True/False which you use to decide if you wanna proceed with the remaining code in the child. This 'control' function can depend on a variable set in the parent class

Having said that, it sounds like an interesting requirement to me. Maybe you need to take another look at your class design and hierarchy.